# Callback function not executing

Tags: javascript, function, callback

The array, that is returned should be `[1,2,3]`, however instead `[3,4,5]` is being logged to the console. Can somebody explain to me why?

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  var newA = []
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newA.push(callback(array[i]));
  }
}

function map(array, callback) {
  forEach(array, callback)
  return array
}

console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2));
```

Comment: You never change `array` - the only thing that ever happens in `forEach` is that you call `callback` with `array[i]`, but as primitives are call-by-value, that won't mutate anything. Did you perhaps mean to `return newA;` in `forEach` and accordingly `return forEach(array,callback);` in `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map()` function requires that `forEach()` modifies the array in place, rather than creating a new array. So it should be:

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = callback(array[i]);
  }
}

function map(array, callback) {
  forEach(array, callback);
  return array;
}

console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2));
```

If `map()` isn't supposed to modify its argument, you could make a copy of the array before calling `forEach()`.

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = callback(array[i]);
  }
}

function map(array, callback) {
  array = array.slice();
  forEach(array, callback);
  return array;
}

var testArray = [3, 4, 5];
console.log(map(testArray, n => n - 2));
console.log(testArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Callback Function not executing

Yes, it does, you just need to return the new array properly

Stack snippet

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  var newA = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newA.push(callback(array[i]));
  }
  return newA;                          // added
}

function map(array, callback) {
  return forEach(array, callback);      // changed
}
console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2));
```

Or deep clone the `array` and clear it, like this

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  var newA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));    // deep clone
  array.length = 0;                                // clear the array
  for (var i = 0; i < newA.length; i++) {
    array.push(callback(newA[i]));
  }
}

function map(array, callback) {
  forEach(array, callback);
  return array
}
console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2));
```

or this

```js
function forEach(array, callback) {
  var newA = array.slice();                        // shallow copy
  array.length = 0;                                // clear the array
  for (var i = 0; i < newA.length; i++) {
    array.push(callback(newA[i]));
  }
}

function map(array, callback) {
  forEach(array, callback);
  return array
}
console.log(map([3, 4, 5], n => n - 2));
```

Comment: So there's no difference between `map()` and `foreach()`?

Comment: @Barmar I answered the title question. Updated with an _in place update of the array_